# adding list controls in angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

i am new to angular js, currently i display the values to  view, using the appviewbatch object, i need to include controls such as list box for appviewbatch.odate with unique values and list box appviewbatch.status with unique values, upon selection of values from both the list box i need to filter and display in the table view..

could you kindly explain how can i do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>
<script src="/LDODashBoard/js/scripts.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/LDODashBoard/css/mystyle.css" /> 
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<div align="center" style="color:white">

<table id="table1"><caption> <STRONG> AppView DisplayPage </STRONG> <br> <br> </caption>
    <tr>
        <td> JobName </td>
        <td> Description </td>
        <td> ODATE </td>
        <td> StartTime </td>        
        <td> EndTime </td>  
        <td> Status </td>   
        <td> RunDuration </td>  
        <td> CyclicJob </td>    
    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${appviewbatch}" var="appview">
            <tr>
                <td> ${appview.jobName}</td>
                <td> ${appview.description}</td>
                <td> ${appview.oDATE}</td>
                <td> ${appview.startTime}</td>
                <td> ${appview.endTime}</td>
                <td> ${appview.status}</td>
                <td> ${appview.runDuration}</td>
                <td> ${appview.cyclicJob}</td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>

<br>
<c:url value="/L1OutputDisplayPage?gcmmLink2=true" var="messageUrl2" />
Click <a href="${messageUrl2}" style="color:yellow" onclick="doSomething('displayContent','/LDODashBoard/L1OutputDisplayPage?','gcmmLink2=true');return false;"> Here</a>
 to Close


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you create an array in your controller. You might populate that array from an HTTP request using Angular's $http service.

In the view, you then use ng-repeat to iterate over items / objects in the array.

check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#example

Comment: Thanks, but this object {appviewbatch} is passed from the spring controller, how to define it in the angular js controller.

Comment: cant you make an http request from angular to spring using angulars $http as suggested?

Comment: <script>
  function Hello($scope, $http) {
         $http.get('http://169.52.203.189:8080/LDODashBoard/AppViewJson.json?appid=CV-APAC-CHECKOUT').
             success(function(data) {
                 $scope.appview = data;
             });
     }
</script>


<select ng-model="test" ng-controller="Hello" ng-options="appview1.oDATE for appview1 in appview">
   <option value="0">Default</option>
</select>

Comment: i created like this but still the option does not display the values